# how to locate a draft in a drafts folder on gmail.com

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'm trying to locate a draft in the Drafts folder to gmail.com, but they are completely dynamic and I do not get it.

```html
<td id=":5p" tabindex="-1" class="xY a4W">
  <div class="xS" role="link">
    <div class="xT"><div class="y6">
      <span id=":5r">test e-mail</span>
      <span class="y2">&nbsp;-&nbsp;It's a test e-mail.</span>  </div></div></div></td>
```

Comment: What error do you getß

Answer (score 0):

if you want to click on it try:

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[@href='https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#drafts']")).Click();
```

or

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[contains(text(),'Drafts')]")).Click();
```

Comment: I am not trying to open drafts folder, I am trying to open single draft in this folder, all I have is a name of the draft

Comment: @СергейЯнкевич начинай с того что есть и по xpath иди к нужному элементу

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("*//div[@class='y6']//span[contains(text(),'test e-mail')]")).Click();
```